# Swift 4 How to simultaneously run two animations on different view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

The idea is pretty basic: I have Label A on View Controller A and Label B on View Controller B. When I tap a button on View Controller A, I will go through the segue to View Controller B. I want the label on View Controller A to Fade out while the label on View Controller B is fading in.

The problem is that as soon as I hit the button on View Controller A to go to View Controller B, the Fade out animation for Label A is skipped and only the Fade in animation for Label B is shown.

I have tried a couple things:

- Set a completion block such that the animation in View controller A finishes before going to View Controller B however this looks choppy; I need the animations to occur simultaneously
- I made a copy of Label A in View Controller B (same coordinates, font size etc..) such that when Label B fades in, Label A can fade out at the same time since they're on the view controller. The problem is this is a very basic example; there is more involved with what I want to actually execute. Things would get messy if I do this method and I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this.

I'm almost certain I'm overlooking something quite basic but I can't seem to figure out a straightforward way to achieve this.

Comment: You might consider having a look at [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) otherwise you'll probably need to consider a implementing your own [custom transition](https://devsign.co/notes/navigation-transitions-1)

Comment: Wow I book marked Hero a long time ago but forgot about it. Thank you for that reminder; I checked out their examples and I think this is the answer I'm looking for. I'll post back here my results

Comment: So actually using Hero gave me the same problem where I had to have the label that I'm trying to animate on both view controllers (if I understood the examples correctly at least. Anyways I found that using ContainerViews gave me the answer I was looking for. I ran into a problem, asked it in another questions here on Stack and just got it solved. I'm happy now so hopefully this will help anyone who is ever in the same boat as me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454153/swift-4-how-to-pass-data-between-viewcontrollers-and-containerviews?noredirect=1#comment99501018_56454153